# installing 12.04 LTS on dell inspiron n3521

Tags: graphics, kubuntu

I am trying to install 12.04 LTS with windows 7 (dual boot)on my dell inspiron n3521 model laptop.

My lap heats up like anything..... Please give a correct solution. On this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The heating issue is mainly caused due to excessive CPU usage. The fact is Ubuntu is a Desktop OS, so heating is not a big issue. So, the solution we can apply here is install a Power Management module (it worked for me).

**Install TLP on Ubuntu**

TLP is an advanced power management command line tool for Linux that tries to apply these settings / tweaks for you automatically, depending on your Linux distribution and hardware.TLP applies these settings automatically on startup and every time you change the power source.

Before proceeding with the installation, there are a couple of things you need to do:

First, if you've added any power saving settings / scripts (e.g.: in /etc/rc.local), remove them or else TLP may not work properly:

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

Ubuntu (and Linux Mint, etc.) users can install TLP by using its official PPA. Add the PPA and install TLP using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

TLP will automatically start upon system startup, but to avoid having to restart the system to get it running for the first time, you can start it (required only the first time) using the following command:

```
sudo tlp start
```

There are some optional packages you can install for some extra features:

smartmontools - needed to display disk drive S.M.A.R.T. data; 
ethtool - needed to disable wake on lan.

Install these tools using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools ethtool
```

While the default TLP configuration should be enough to provide optimized power saving out of the box, you can modify the TLP settings and access some advanced features by editing the TLP configuration file called "tlp" located under /etc/default/. To open this file as root with Gedit, use the following command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

Make any changes you like, then save the file and to apply the changes, either reboot the system or simply run

```
sudo tlp start
```

For Ubuntu 14.10, you can use Linux Thermal Daemon (thermald) which is a tool developed by Intel's Open Source Technology Center which monitors and controls the CPU temperature, preventing it from overheating.

Comment: Which Ubuntu releases will use less CPU, and perform more.... Can I install 10.04 LTS instead 12.04 LTS.

Comment: What is the difference b/w Long Term Support to other versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: A new LTS version is released every 2 years. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, both versions will receive 5 years support. Other versions receive updates only for 6 months, then a new version is released. You can try Linux Mint, a derivative of Ubuntu. Whatever OS you use, it is a good idea to install a Power Management Tool. If you think I've helped, please upvote or mark as answer my answer so that it is useful for a wider audience.

Comment: Is extended partition harms on dual boot .....?

Comment: I have 19 GB disk space for Ubuntu installation .... But this 19 GB is extended partition .....so is this affects the dual boot?

Comment: No. It won't affect. An Extended partition is present as only 4 primary partitions are allowed. In my dual boot setup I installed Ubuntu on such a partition.

Comment: Can you tell me the brief procedure of installing TLP power management tool in terminal. Plz.....

Comment: Battery can't stand for a longer period.... And fan sounds more, when comparing the performance with windows.... Why this happens, what is the technical reason?

Comment: When the CPU works faster, it gets hotter, hence fan runs faster to keep it cool hence the increase in sound. Same for battery backup. I already explained that in my post. All the steps are clearly mentioned in my post. There is nothing more to do. Open a terminal and copy+paste these commands in order.

Comment: Dear, I am face a problem in Ubuntu, when I click shut down button, Ubuntu returns to login screen, but it won't shutdown. Why ? What is the problem .....?

Comment: I liked your answers, but I can't find upvote button here(I am using mobile) can plz tell me where is upvote button..... Such that, other beginners will help with this....

Comment: How can I know TLP of installed on my Ubuntu.?

Comment: Please post a new question on the shut down issue. If you followed the steps, it is installed. It's okay if you can't upvote. I have not used the site through mobile, I'm not sure as well.